# What does 자차 mean in terms of driving?

Tags: spoken-korean

자차 - Does this mean driving a car alone? Does it mean solo driving or perhaps solo driver?

Comment: I'm curious where you saw this, or what the context was.  Regardless, @gaeguri is going to be correct; however, it is still probably useful for learning where one might see this (besides 자차보험).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

자차 (自車) means "own car".

It's normally heard in the expression 자차보험 "own car insurance" - which means auto insurance in which your own car is covered.  I haven't heard it used outside of that expression though.